# (PHP) If statement stupidity

Tags: php, if-statement

This code checks if a pin is correct or not.
This is the code for the login/index page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <h1>
        Project_01
    </h1>
    <h2>
        Please enter access pin.
    </h2>
    <form action="checker.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="pin"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

Which works fine. But my code to check if the pin is right turns up as a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p>
        <?php
            $enc = $GET_["pin"];

        if($enc == "7885") {
            echo ("User Login.");
        elseif($enc == "5296"):
            echo ("Admin Login");
        else:
            echo ("Error.");
        }
        ?>
    </p>
</html>
```

Either it prints out the rest of my code, or all of the if statements return true. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably just an accidental typo, but it should be changed from

```
$enc = $GET_["pin"];
```

to

```
$enc = $_GET["pin"];
```

Also, this is better formatting with brackets:

```
<?php
$enc = $_GET["pin"];

if($enc == "7885") {
    echo "User Login.";
} elseif ($enc == "5296") {
    echo "Admin Login";
} else {
    echo "Error.";
}
```

Comment: It's still blankscreening :/. Thanks for the formatting help though.

Comment: Did you fix `$enc = $_GET["pin"];`?

Comment: Yeah, but its still blank. Could there be a problem with my condition?

Comment: The final `else` should print "Error.", and it does in my test code. Is there any more PHP? The HTML looks incomplete so I'm wondering if there is more. Also, enable errors if you haven't done so already. Also, view the source of the blank page and see if there is any html output at all, like those `<p>` tags.

Comment: That's all I have so far. Maybe its a problem with my browser. But it just blank-screens every time i try.

Comment: I made a test for you here: http://ideone.com/8Z9s9K. All works well. There must something up with your server. Any ideas? Also, enable errors if you haven't done so already. Also, view the source of the blank page and see if there is any html output at all, like those `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Remove brackets

```
    if($enc == "7885") 
        echo ("User Login.");
    elseif($enc == "5296"):
        echo ("Admin Login");
    else
        echo ("Error.");
```

Now elses used only when `if($enc == "7885")` is true

Comment: Still no change. Blank screen as usual.

Answer (score 0):

```
$enc = $GET_["pin"];
```

above code is wrong, it will "$_GET['']". correction is below.

```
$enc = $_GET["pin"];
    if($enc == "7885") :
        echo ("User Login.");
    elseif($enc == "5296"):
        echo ("Admin Login");
    else:
        echo ("Error.");
    endif;
```

Comment: Nope. :/ Blank screen.

Comment: My below code is correct, I think that you can copy and paste. replace your code by my code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure its a browser problem, cause its still a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **PHP** code to:

```
     <?php
        $enc = $_GET["pin"];

        if($enc == "7885") {
            echo "User Login.";
          }
        elseif($enc == "5296"){
            echo "Admin Login";
          }
        else{
            echo "Error.";
          }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm beginning to think its a problem with my browser. It's still a blank screen.

Comment: @user3429292, after submit button, are you in `checker.php` page?